# Binary search not working for all test cases

Tags: java, binary-search

I'm trying to implement a recursive binary search in Java, however, it it not working for all test cases. I am doing a Hacker rank challenge, and it is not showing me the test cases I've missed. When I test it with my own cases, it always tests successfully. I don't know what I'm missing.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Project {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        int[] arr = {1,2,4,7,9,10,11};

        Arrays.sort(arr);

        String x = findNumber(arr, 10);
        System.out.println(x);
    }

     private static String findNumber(int[] arr, int k) {
             int arrLength = arr.length - 1;

             int mid = Math.round(Math.abs((arrLength) / 2));
             if (arrLength >= mid){
                 if (arr[mid] == k) {
                     return "YES";
                 }

                 else if (arr[mid] > k) {
                     int[] newArr = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, mid);
                     return findNumber(newArr, k);
                 }

                 else if (arr[mid] < k) {
                     int[] newArr = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, mid + 1, arrLength + 1);
                     return findNumber(newArr, k);
                 }
             }

        return "NO";
     }
}
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What are the edge cases you have tried? Could it be that it errors out for a large sample size?

Comment: Please don't copy the array on every recursive step.

Comment: @clinomaniac I have tried relatively small array sizes (2-12), but all seem to be working. I wish Hacker rank would show what test cases it's testing.

Comment: @Bytes I have seem some sites which have a test case with a really large sample size so that might be throwing an exception on Array copy or something. I don't see anything wrong with the algorithm as such except for performance.

Comment: @clinomaniac How would I change the array copying part to increase performance?

Comment: The approach normally taken for this kind of a problem is to not copy the array. Instead use a helper function and have multiple pointers for start and end. With each recursion call, you move the start and end towards the middle and reference the same array.

Comment: @clinomaniac Yes, i'm familiar with that approach, but I was hoping to see if I could do it with their function that contains only 2 parameters

Comment: What exactly is the challenge?  Maybe it needs to execute within a certain amount of time?

Comment: 'Hoping to see if I could do it with their function that only takes parameters' is futile if it forces you into copying the data. Binary search is suppose to be *fast*. You might as well write a linear search.

Comment: Write a better, write at all a testmethod, that takes an array, a value and an expected result. Write an arraygenerating method. Write loops, to produce massive testcases yourself. For binary search, the corner cases are of course left bound, right bound, and test with even and odd array sizes. While I did that border- and even/odd-thing, I didn't find an error, however.

Answer (score 0):

You're coding too much and thinking not enough.

First, the base case.  If the array is of zero length, return `"NO"`. You can't find `k` in a zero-length array.

Now the recursive case. The array has at least 1 element. Think of it as split it into *3* parts: a single element that's roughly in the middle plus two additional subarrays of length zero or more.  You *always* have a middle element because the array has at least one element.

The index computation `int mid = a.length / 2` will work fine to locate the middle. (Dump the rounding and absolute value.) The remaining sub arrays have index ranges `0..mid-1` and `mid+1..a.length-1`.

With `mid`, you can immediately check to see if `a[mid]` is a match. If it is return `"YES"`.

Otherwise you'll need to figure out in which subarray `k` lies and search that recursively.

DON'T make a copy to build the subarray. Use the `List` method [`subList(from, to)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList(int,%20int)). This needs only constant space. It's just a view into the input array, not a copy into new memory.  Much more efficient.

To use `subList`, your algorithm will need to accept a `List` rather than a native Java array.

Note that `subList`'s second parameter is *exclusive*, so the recursive calls will be on `a.sublist(0, mid)` or `a.sublist(mid+1, a.length)`.

Note that the two subarray alternatives are *always* shorter than `a`. This guarantees that your algorithm will eventually terminate, i.e. not recur infinitely. If you shorten the array at each recursive call, you must eventually get to the base case, which always returns.

You'll need to work out some additional details, but not many.